# Add CSS element after kendogrid refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-grid, asp.net-ajax, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax call that sends to MyAction in MyController.. it returns me with result of success and an Id for an element to which I want to attach some CSS.

the Id is returned, and the css is added but the refreshGridData happens afterwards removing the css I just added to the element.

Is there a way to wait for refreshGridData to finish and then add the css?

I did try the done for ajax.. it did not work.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                alert("success");
                refreshGridData();
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error!");
        }
        AddMyCSSToThis(result.Id);
       // done: AddMyCSSToThis(result.Id);
    }); 

    function refreshGridData() {
        var ajaxContainer = $(".grid-wrap");
        kendo.ui.progress(ajaxContainer, true);
        refreshGrid();
        kendo.ui.progress(ajaxContainer, false);
    }
```

Comment: Why does the refreshGrid function calls itself in your example?

Comment: You are calling `refreshGridData();` in the success callback but the function is called `refreshGrid()` ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake when placing the function here. It is supposed to be refreshGridData() which has an function refreshGrid();

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle updated it.

Comment: @MartinD. updated the question.

Comment: Could you post the entire Kendo Grid and the refreshGrid function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you pass in the Id you want to add the change into your refreshGridData() function like:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")",
    type: "POST",
    data: postData,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.Success) {
            alert("success");
            var savedId = result.Id;
            refreshGridData(savedId);
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error!");
    }
    AddMyCSSToThis(result.Id);
   // done: AddMyCSSToThis(result.Id);
}); 

function refreshGridData(savedId) {
    var ajaxContainer = $(".grid-wrap");
    kendo.ui.progress(ajaxContainer, true);
    refreshGrid(savedId); // I'm assuming this function is what adds the css
    kendo.ui.progress(ajaxContainer, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a global variable and use it in the grid dataBound event to add the CSS.

```
_addCssToResultId = null;
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")",
    type: "POST",
    data: postData,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.Success) {
            alert("success");
            _addCssToResultId = result.Id;
            refreshGridData();
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error!");
    }
});

// add a dataBound handler to your grid
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataBound: function(e) {
    if(_addCssToResultId) {
       AddMyCSSToThis(_addCssToResultId);
       _addCssToResultId = null;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It did not work.. I declared the variable  on document ready and this did not work unfortunately ..

Comment: Try declraing the variable outside of document ready or else it won't be in the global scope or remove the var keyword in front of the variable name.

Comment: This did not work either for me .. just before the script begins before document ready with and without var.